# PyQt5 on android

Tags: android, qt, pyqt

I was wondering if someone could explain to me how you make your PyQt5 application run on Android. The documentation is not very explicit regarding Android to say the least.

I am building on a Kubuntu desktop. I have Android NDK and SDK installed, I have Qt 5.5.1 for android.

I don't know how to proceed from here. I tried building PyQt5 for android like I would build it for Linux:

```
ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=<MY_NDK_INSTALLATION> python configure.py -q <PATH_TO_ANDROID_QMAKE>
```

but that just returns the following error:

```
Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
Determining the details of your Qt installation...
/home/jakob/Qt/5.5/android_armv7/bin/qmake -o qtdetail.mk qtdetail.pro
make -f qtdetail.mk
/home/jakob/dev/android/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -c -Wno-psabi -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=vfp -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-short-enums -DANDROID -Wa,--noexecstack -fno-builtin-memmove -std=c++11 -O2 -Os -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -mthumb -Wall -Wno-psabi -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -I../../../Qt/5.5/android_armv7/include -I../../../Qt/5.5/android_armv7/include/QtCore -I. -I../../android/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include -I../../android/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi-v7a/include -I../../android/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include -I../../../Qt/5.5/android_armv7/mkspecs/android-g++ -o qtdetail.o qtdetail.cpp
/home/jakob/dev/android/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ --sysroot=/home/jakob/dev/android/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/ -Wl,-soname,libqtdetail.so -Wl,-rpath=/home/jakob/Qt/5.5/android_armv7/lib -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -shared -o libqtdetail.so qtdetail.o   -L/home/jakob/dev/android/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi-v7a -L/home/jakob/dev/android/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-9/arch-arm//usr/lib -L/home/jakob/Qt/5.5/android_armv7/lib -lQt5Core -L/opt/android/ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi-v7a -L/opt/android/ndk/platforms/android-9/arch-arm//usr/lib -lgnustl_shared -llog -lz -lm -ldl -lc -lgcc
Error: Failed to determine the detail of your Qt installation. Try again using
the --verbose flag to see more detail about the problem.
```

Can anybody give a hint?

It would really be nice if someone could provide a guide to using PyQt5 on Android.

Answer (score 0):

The code of qtdetail just generates a plain-text config so I ran its source on my Android-device and got this:

```
Open Source
shared
PyQt_Desktop_OpenGL
```

If you can not repeat my steps, you can apply this patch to configure.py (for Unix-like platforms)

```
697,698c697,699
<         cmd = compile_qt_program(self, verbose, 'qtdetail', source, 'QtCore',
<                 debug=debug)
---
>         # cmd = compile_qt_program(self, verbose, 'qtdetail', source, 'QtCore',
>         #         debug=debug)
>         cmd = """echo "Open Source\nshared\nPyQt_Desktop_OpenGL" > qtdetail.out"""
```